# Android TextView with a concatenated value get localized

Tags: android, localization, android-support-library, simpledateformat

I am trying to use localization for an Android app. I have a problem with one textView who's value is concatenated as follow:

```
holder.downloadDate.setText(getContext().getString(R.string.downloaded_title) + " " + downloadedItem.getDownloadDate());
```

and here is getDownloadedDate method:

```
public String getDownloadDate() {
.....
    return DateUtils.formatDateTime(context, file.lastModified(), DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR | DateUtils.FORMAT_NUMERIC_DATE);
}
```

my problem is that when I change localization all is fine but the textView value get whole changed (the translated text string  + the date itself), I want keep the date as it is like for ex : 2019/01/29 and not in a rtl format.

is there a way to do that?

Comment: Why? People in different cultures write and read dates differently, so why not adhere to that when you can? If this is for machine readability, use [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). It’s better than inventing your own format.

Comment: I used local with country code and it’s solved.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Calendar and get the current year and month and day and concatenate those and eventually use String.format to format the numbers on 2 digits.